# How can I add InputScope property to PasswordBox in WinRT?

Tags: user-controls, windows-runtime, custom-controls, passwordbox, inputscope

How can I add Input Scope property to my User Control's PasswordBox?

Could you explain it to me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by input scope? Like displaying only number keys on the virtual keyboard for a PasswordBox that only supports digits as input? I might agree with @tanuj_loop that indeed - you might need to create your own control, which is non-trivial. You should probably support pasting, but not copying out of the control, handle all the key modifiers like Ctrl+Arrow, Shift+Arrow, etc. - possibly dozens of combinations. That on top of designing your own touch UI and handling and validating input.

Comment: I got it but it is already my custom control, and I am trying to add to it. You are talking about change passwordbox in my customcontrol?
@Filip Skakun thanks a million for being my teacher :)

Comment: A new question to you :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796893/error-when-uploading-file-with-backgrounduploadasync-in-wp8

Comment: I submitted [feedback](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579/suggestions/4433511) for Microsoft to review.  Please vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

according to the information i have PasswordBox does not have Input Scope Property in winrt so you can't set it directly. if you want do it you have to make your separate custom control. For defining your own Custom control you have read it on **Windows Development Center**..or simply google it..hope it helps you..
you can use [this](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx) link..

Comment: you actually you have to take a textbox and set its input scope..using dependency property..( what i am trying to say is you have make your passwordbox from scratch using textbox and other control..you don't have to take passwordbox directly..because problem will remain the same ..)